# Spring Boot with spring schedulers

Tags: spring-boot

what are the benefits of spring boot and will it download all the related jars automatically in the local repo.I tried with normal spring approach and wanted to know benefits with spring boot

Comment: Read the documentation. That's, among other things, what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be mainly interested in these:

- Minimizes boilerplate code (XML, Annotations, etc..)
- Provides you with Embedded application server (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow). This means that you will be able to run your application with "java -jar your-artefact.jar", it will start application server itself. Without this feature you would deploy your WAR artefact into already existing application server.

And answering to your question "will it download all the related jars automatically in the local repo" it will if use will use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter. "starter" notion means that it will download everything needed for it to work.